# Creating vector index in neo4j " {message: Invalid input 'VECTOR': expected "(", "allShortestPaths" or "shortestPath" (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))"

Tags: python, neo4j

Running the below cypher query to create vector index for my node (n:Paragraph) generates a cypher syntax error. I took the sample out of the Neo4j cypher manual. I run the query from jupyter notebook and directly on the neo4j browser but no help.

CREATE VECTOR INDEX abstract-embeddings
FOR (n: Paragraph) ON (n.embedding)
OPTIONS {indexConfig: {
`vector.dimensions`: 1536,
`vector.similarity_function`: 'cosine'}}

I tried running the Cypher query on the web browser and from jupyter notebook but no help. This the neo4j version I am running: Neo4j Browser version: 5.15.0, Neo4j Server version: 5.4.0 (enterprise)

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation, you should see beautiful green flashing labels telling you from which Neo4j version the VECTOR indexes are available. Since you're on Neo4j 5.4, you're 11 versions behind the version that supports VECTOR indexes

[image]

Nevertheless, the neo4j docs forgot to escape the names containing dashes or dots

This works without issues on 5.15

```
CREATE VECTOR INDEX `abstract-embeddings` 
FOR (n: Paragraph) ON (n.embedding) 
OPTIONS {indexConfig: { 
  `vector.dimensions`: 1536, 
  `vector.similarity_function`: 'cosine'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work, just upgrade your database to 15.5 not the browser.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCjlG.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).